# Weekly sales total divided by monthly membership total based on dates

Tags: pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I am trying to divide each weeks and months sales total by the membership_count based on the Date and Membership_Mth_Yr. So if the sales Date is in December 2022 I want it to divide the weekly Sales by the Membership_Count that is for the month of December 2022. I need to be able to do that for all months and for multiple years. Below is a snipped of the dataframes. The data is in two dataframes. One is Sales_data and the other is Membership_data.

```
         **Sales df**                                     **Membership df**
Month    DOW    Date        Sales            Membership_Count   Membership_Mth_Yr
December Thu    2022-12-01  126              73480          2022-12-01 00:00:00
```

---

I've already cleaned the data.

```
## Convert Date and Membmership Mth_Yr columns to datetime64 dtype
sales_data['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(sales_data['Date'])

sales_data['Membership_Mth_Yr'] = pd.to_datetime(sales_data['Membership_Mth_Yr'], errors='coerce', format='%b-%y')

## How i grouped the weekly and monthly sales data
sales_weekly_sum = sales_data.groupby(['Month', pd.Grouper(key='Date', freq='W-Fri')])['Sales'].sum().reset_index().sort_values('Date')

sales_monthly_sum = sales_data.groupby(['Month', pd.Grouper(key='Date', freq='M')])['Sales'].sum().reset_index().sort_values('Date')
```

I thought maybe making the sum dfs and the membership df into a dictionary would help but can't figure out to make it work. I feel like a loop is needed as well but I am not to familiar with loops

Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

Because there isn't a lot of data to work with, the following should get you pointed in the right direction as a possible solution. df1 is the sales data and df2 is the membership data. For each, I create a 'YrMo' column (you can do the same for weekly on your own). Then group each dataframe by 'YrMo' to get the totals.

Sales dataframe

```
df1['YrMo'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Date']).dt.strftime('%Y-%m')
df1_grp = df1.groupby('YrMo').agg(MonthlySales=('Sales', 'sum'))
df1_grp
```

df1_grp

```
         MonthlySales
YrMo
2022-12           126
```

Membership dataframe

```
df2 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data2), sep=' \s+', engine='python')
df2['YrMo'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Membership_Mth_Yr']).dt.strftime('%Y-%m')
df2_grp = df2.groupby('YrMo').agg(MonthlyMembership=('Membership_Count', 'sum'))
df2_grp
```

df2_grp

```
         MonthlyMembership
YrMo
2022-12              73480
```

Then merge the two and calculate averages

```
dfaverages = df1_grp.merge(df2_grp, left_index=True, right_index=True)
dfaverages['MonthlyAvgSales'] = dfaverages['MonthlySales'] / dfaverages['MonthlyMembership']
```

dfaverages

```
         MonthlySales  MonthlyMembership  MonthlyAvgSales
YrMo
2022-12           126              73480         0.001715
```